# Return limited number of records of a certain type, but unlimited number of other records?

Tags: javascript, php, mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

I have a query where I need to return 10 of "Type A" records, while returning all other records. How can I accomplish this?

**Update:** Admittedly, I could do this with two queries, but I wanted to avoid that, if possible, thinking it would be less overhead, and possibly more performant. My query already is an aggregation query that takes both kinds of records into account, I just need to limit the number of the one type of record in the results.

**Update:** the following is an example query that highlights the problem:

```
db.books.aggregate([
    {$geoNear: {near: [-118.09771, 33.89244], distanceField: "distance", spherical: true}},
    {$match:    {"type": "Fiction"}},
    {$project:  {
        'title': 1,
        'author': 1,
        'type': 1,
        'typeSortOrder': 
            {$add: [
                {$cond: [{$eq: ['$type', "Fiction"]}, 1, 0]},
                {$cond: [{$eq: ['$type', "Science"]}, 0, 0]},
                {$cond: [{$eq: ['$type', "Horror"]}, 3, 0]}
        ]},
    }},
    {$sort: {'typeSortOrder'}},
    {$limit: 10}
])

db.books.aggregate([
    {$geoNear: {near: [-118.09771, 33.89244], distanceField: "distance", spherical: true}},
    {$match:    {"type": "Horror"}},
    {$project:  {
        'title': 1,
        'author': 1,
        'type': 1,
        'typeSortOrder': 
            {$add: [
                {$cond: [{$eq: ['$type', "Fiction"]}, 1, 0]},
                {$cond: [{$eq: ['$type', "Science"]}, 0, 0]},
                {$cond: [{$eq: ['$type', "Horror"]}, 3, 0]}
        ]},
    }},
    {$sort: {'typeSortOrder'}},
    {$limit: 10}
])

db.books.aggregate([
    {$geoNear: {near: [-118.09771, 33.89244], distanceField: "distance", spherical: true}},
    {$match:    {"type": "Science"}},
    {$project:  {
        'title': 1,
        'author': 1,
        'type': 1,
        'typeSortOrder': 
            {$add: [
                {$cond: [{$eq: ['$type', "Fiction"]}, 1, 0]},
                {$cond: [{$eq: ['$type', "Science"]}, 0, 0]},
                {$cond: [{$eq: ['$type', "Horror"]}, 3, 0]}
        ]},
    }},
    {$sort: {'typeSortOrder'}},
    {$limit: 10}
])
```

I would like to have all these records returned in one query, but limit the type to at most 10 of any category.
I realize that the typeSortOrder doesn't need to be conditional when the queries are broken out like this, I had it there for when the queries were one query, originally (which is where I would like to get back to).

Comment: That kinda sounds to me like two different queries... Could you give some more context so that we might suggest an alternative approach?

Comment: You can easily do this with the aggregation framework, but as to whether it would be more performant...hmmm, I cannot actually tell you

Comment: @Sammaye could you expand on that? How can I achieve this using aggregation? Can I chain aggregation queries so that the results of 3 queries are returned in one result set? I have 3 separate queries running at the moment, which is significantly slower than running a single query (albeit without the $limit for the types of fields).

Comment: Can you show us what queries you are running? I am surprised this would be slower than aggregation. But you can per document create three fields into another document which contains the sums your looking for

Comment: @Sammaye Updated question with example. :)

Comment: Ah that would explain why, can you try without the aggregate, just find({type:'Science'}).limit(10) etc with an index in type?

Comment: To follow up on the whole idea of using aggregate, I believe that due to the limit of each group it would actually be faster to shoot three queries off than use aggregate here

Comment: I actually need aggregate() for other reasons (distance using geoNear, etc.).

Comment: Can you show your entire queries? We need to see what we are up against here

Comment: @Sammaye updated with more complete example.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers so far. I agree that at this time the best method is to proceed with joining the query results in the application logic due to the limitations of MongoDB. All answers are valuable, but I must award the bounty to Neil for the most complete, exhaustive, as well as plausible solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem

---

The results here are not impossible but are also possibly impractical. The general notes have been made that you cannot "slice" an array or otherwise "limit" the amount of results pushed onto one. And the method for doing this per "type" is essentially to use arrays.

The "impractical" part is usually about the number of results, where too large a result set is going to blow up the BSON document limit when "grouping". But, I'm going to consider this with some other recommendations on your "geo search" along with the ultimate goal to return 10 results of each "type" at most.

### Principle

---

To first consider and understand the problem, let's look at a simplified "set" of data and the pipeline code necessary to return the "top 2 results" from each type:

```js
{ "title": "Title 1", "author": "Author 1", "type": "Fiction", "distance": 1 },
{ "title": "Title 2", "author": "Author 2", "type": "Fiction", "distance": 2 },
{ "title": "Title 3", "author": "Author 3", "type": "Fiction", "distance": 3 },
{ "title": "Title 4", "author": "Author 4", "type": "Science", "distance": 1 },
{ "title": "Title 5", "author": "Author 5", "type": "Science", "distance": 2 },
{ "title": "Title 6", "author": "Author 6", "type": "Science", "distance": 3 },
{ "title": "Title 7", "author": "Author 7", "type": "Horror", "distance": 1 }
```

That's a simplified view of the data and somewhat representative of the state of documents after an initial query. Now comes the trick of how to use the aggregation pipeline to get the "nearest" two results for each "type":

```js
db.books.aggregate([
    { "$sort": { "type": 1, "distance": 1 } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$type",
        "1": { 
            "$first": {
                "_id": "$_id",
                "title": "$title",
                "author": "$author",
                "distance": "$distance"
            }
         },
         "books": {
             "$push": {
                "_id": "$_id",
                "title": "$title",
                "author": "$author",
                "distance": "$distance"
              }
         }
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "1": 1,
        "books": {
            "$cond": [
                { "$eq": [ { "$size": "$books" }, 1 ] },
                { "$literal": [false] },
                "$books"
            ]
        }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$books" },
    { "$project": {
        "1": 1,
        "books": 1,
        "seen": { "$eq": [ "$1", "$books" ] }
    }},
    { "$sort": { "_id": 1, "seen": 1 } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "1": { "$first": "$1" },
        "2": { "$first": "$books" },
        "books": {
            "$push": {
                "$cond": [ { "$not": "$seen" }, "$books", false ]
            }
        }
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "1": 1,
        "2": 2,
        "pos": { "$literal": [1,2] }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$pos" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "books": {
            "$push": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$pos", 1 ] },
                    "$1",
                    { "$cond": [
                        { "$eq": [ "$pos", 2 ] },
                        "$2",
                        false
                    ]}
                ]
            }
        }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$books" },
    { "$match": { "books": { "$ne": false } } },
    { "$project": {
        "_id": "$books._id",
        "title": "$books.title",
        "author": "$books.author",
        "type": "$_id",
        "distance": "$books.distance",
        "sortOrder": {
            "$add": [
                { "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$_id", "Fiction" ] }, 1, 0 ] },
                { "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$_id", "Science" ] }, 0, 0 ] },
                { "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$_id", "Horror" ] }, 3, 0 ] }
            ]
        }
    }},
    { "$sort": { "sortOrder": 1 } }
])
```

Of course that is just two results, but it outlines the process for getting `n` results, which naturally is done in generated pipeline code. Before moving onto the code the process deserves a walk through.

After any query, the first thing to do here is [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) the results, and this you want to basically do by both the "grouping key" which is the "type" and by the "distance" so that the "nearest" items are on top.

The reason for this is shown in the [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stages that will repeat. What is done is essentially "popping the [**`$first`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) result off of each grouping stack. So other documents are not lost, they are placed in an array using [**`$push`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/).

Just to be safe, the next stage is really only required after the "first step", but could optionally be added for similar filtering in the repetition. The main check here is that the resulting "array" is larger than just **one** item. Where it is not, the contents are replaced with a single value of false. The reason for which is about to become evident.

After this "first step" the real repetition cycle beings, where that array is then "de-normalized" with [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and then a [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) made in order to "match" the document that has been last "seen".

As only one of the documents will match this condition the results are again "sorted" in order to float the "unseen" documents to the top, while of course maintaining the grouping order. The next thing is similar to the first `$group` step, but where any kept positions are maintained and the "first unseen" document is "popped off the stack" again.

The document that was "seen" is then pushed back to the array not as itself but as a value of `false`. This is not going to match the kept value and this is generally the way to handle this without being "destructive" to the array contents where you don't want the operations to fail should there not be enough matches to cover the `n` results required.

Cleaning up when complete, the next "projection" adds an array to the final documents now grouped by "type" representing each position in the `n` results required. When this array is unwound, the documents can again be grouped back together, but now all in a single array
that possibly contains several `false` values but is `n` elements long.

Finally unwind the array again, use [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) to filter out the `false` values, and project to the required document form.

### Practicality

---

The problem as stated earlier is with the number of results being filtered as there is a real limit on the number of results that can be pushed into an array. That is mostly the BSON limit, but you also don't really want 1000's of items even if that is still under the limit.

The trick here is keeping the initial "match" small enough that the "slicing operations" becomes practical. There are some things with the [**`$geoNear`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/) pipeline process that can make this a possibility.

The obvious is `limit`. By default this is 100 but you clearly want to have something in the range of:

> (the number of categories you can possibly match) X ( required matches )

But if this is essentially a number not in the 1000's then there is already some help here.

The others are `maxDistance` and `minDistance`, where essentially you put upper and lower bounds on how "far out" to search. The max bound is the general limiter while the min bound is useful when "paging", which is the next helper.

When "upwardly paging", you can use the `query` argument in order to exclude the `_id` values of documents "already seen" using the [**`$nin`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/) query. In much the same way, the `minDistance` can be populated with the "last seen" largest distance, or at least the smallest largest distance by "type". This allows some concept of filtering out things that have already been "seen" and getting another page.

Really a topic in itself, but those are the general things to look for in reducing that initial match in order to make the process practical.

### Implementing

---

The general problem of returning "10 results at most, per type" is clearly going to want some code in order to generate the pipeline stages. No-one wants to type that out, and practically speaking you will probably want to change that number at some point.

So now to the code that can generate the monster pipeline. All code in JavaScript, but easy to translate in principles:

```js
var coords = [-118.09771, 33.89244];

var key = "$type";
var val = {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "title": "$title",
    "author": "$author",
    "distance": "$distance"
};
var maxLen = 10;

var stack = [];
var pipe = [];
var fproj = { "$project": { "pos": { "$literal": []  } } };

pipe.push({ "$geoNear": {
    "near": coords, 
    "distanceField": "distance", 
    "spherical": true
}});

pipe.push({ "$sort": {
    "type": 1, "distance": 1
}});

for ( var x = 1; x <= maxLen; x++ ) {

    fproj["$project"][""+x] = 1;
    fproj["$project"]["pos"]["$literal"].push( x );

    var rec = {
        "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$pos", x ] }, "$"+x ]
    };
    if ( stack.length == 0 ) {
        rec["$cond"].push( false );
    } else {
        lval = stack.pop();
        rec["$cond"].push( lval );
    }

    stack.push( rec );

    if ( x == 1) {
        pipe.push({ "$group": {
           "_id": key,
           "1": { "$first": val },
           "books": { "$push": val }
        }});
        pipe.push({ "$project": {
           "1": 1,
           "books": {
               "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [ { "$size": "$books" }, 1 ] },
                    { "$literal": [false] },
                    "$books"
               ]
           }
        }});
    } else {
        pipe.push({ "$unwind": "$books" });
        var proj = {
            "$project": {
                "books": 1
            }
        };

        proj["$project"]["seen"] = { "$eq": [ "$"+(x-1), "$books" ] };

        var grp = {
            "$group": {
                "_id": "$_id",
                "books": {
                    "$push": {
                        "$cond": [ { "$not": "$seen" }, "$books", false ]
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        for ( n=x; n >= 1; n-- ) {
            if ( n != x ) 
                proj["$project"][""+n] = 1;
            grp["$group"][""+n] = ( n == x ) ? { "$first": "$books" } : { "$first": "$"+n };
        }

        pipe.push( proj );
        pipe.push({ "$sort": { "_id": 1, "seen": 1 } });
        pipe.push(grp);
    }
}

pipe.push(fproj);
pipe.push({ "$unwind": "$pos" });
pipe.push({
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "msgs": { "$push": stack[0] }
    }
});
pipe.push({ "$unwind": "$books" });
pipe.push({ "$match": { "books": { "$ne": false } }});
pipe.push({
    "$project": {
        "_id": "$books._id",
        "title": "$books.title",
        "author": "$books.author",
        "type": "$_id",
        "distance": "$books",
        "sortOrder": {
            "$add": [
                { "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$_id", "Fiction" ] }, 1, 0 ] },
                { "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$_id", "Science" ] }, 0, 0 ] },
                { "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$_id", "Horror" ] }, 3, 0 ] },
            ]
        }
    }
});
pipe.push({ "$sort": { "sortOrder": 1, "distance": 1 } });
```

### Alternate

---

Of course the end result here and the general problem with all above is that you really only want the "top 10" of each "type" to return. The aggregation pipeline will do it, but at the cost of keeping more than 10 and then "popping off the stack" until 10 is reached.

An alternate approach is to "brute force" this with mapReduce and "globally scoped" variables. Not as nice since the results all in arrays, but it may be a practical approach:

```js
db.collection.mapReduce(
    function () {

        if ( !stash.hasOwnProperty(this.type) ) {
            stash[this.type] = [];
        }

        if ( stash[this.type.length < maxLen ) {
            stash[this.type].push({
                "title": this.title,
                "author": this.author,
                "type": this.type,
                "distance": this.distance
            });
            emit( this.type, 1 );
        }

    },
    function(key,values) {
        return 1;   // really just want to keep the keys
    },
    { 
        "query": {
            "location": {
                "$nearSphere": [-118.09771, 33.89244]
            }
        },
        "scope": { "stash": {}, "maxLen": 10 },
        "finalize": function(key,value) {
            return { "msgs": stash[key] };                
        },
        "out": { "inline": 1 }
    }
)
```

This is a real cheat which just uses the "global scope" to keep a single object whose keys are the grouping keys. The results are pushed onto an array in that global object until the maximum length is reached. Results are already sorted by nearest, so the mapper just gives up doing anything with the current document after the 10 are reached per key.

The reducer wont be called since only 1 document per key is emitted. The finalize then just "pulls" the value from the global and returns it in the result.

Simple, but of course you don't have all the `$geoNear` options if you really need them, and this form has the hard limit of 100 document as the output from the initial query.

Comment: That's some pretty epic pipeline wrangling .. cool to see that it might be possible (if impractical) to calculate :). I do think this misses a key part of the original question which is "thinking it would be less overhead, and possibly more performant". The end goal isn't necessarily to always do everything in a single query or aggregation; this is a case where two aggregations would be simpler and more performant (at least until there is a `$group` accumulator to support doing this efficiently).

Comment: @Stennie Agreed. In fact where available I would generally suggest running parallel queries and combining the results. Seemed worth mentioning considering that there should be ways to make the initial match not contain more than a few hundred documents. But otherwise generally impractical.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this is presently (2.6) possible to do with one aggregation pipeline. It's difficult to give a precise argument as to why not, but basically the aggregation pipeline performs transformations of streams of documents, one document at a time. There's no awareness within the pipeline of the state of the stream itself, which is what you'd need to determine that you've hit the limit for A's, B's, etc and need to drop further documents of the same type. `$group` does bring multiple documents together and allows their field values in aggregate to affect the resulting group document (`$sum`, `$avg`, etc.). Maybe this makes some sense, but it's necessarily not rigorous because there are simple operations you could add to make it possible to limit based on the types, e.g., adding a `$push x` accumulator to `$group` that only pushes the value if the array being pushed to has fewer than x elements.

Even if I did have a way to do it, I'd recommend just doing two aggregations. Keep it simple.

Comment: A relevant feature request to upvote/watch is: [SERVER-9377: Extend $push or $max to allow collecting "top" N values per _id key in $group phase](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9377).

Comment: Much as @Stennie says, the issue is a waiting feature request. But "impossible" (sic) is a big call. Impractical might fit, but that is what I basically describe in an answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic case for subquery/join which is not supported by MongoDB. All joins and subquery-like operations need to be implemented in the application logic. So multiple queries is your best bet. Performance of the multiple query approach should be good if you have an index on type.

Alternatively you can write a single aggregation query minus the type-matching and limit clauses and then process the stream in your application logic to limit documents per type.
This approach will be low on performance for large result sets because documents may be returned in random order. Your limiting logic will then need to traverse to the entire result set.

Answer (score 2):

i guess you can use cursor.limit() on a cursor to specify the maximum number of documents the cursor will return. limit() is analogous to the LIMIT statement in a SQL database.
You must apply limit() to the cursor before retrieving any documents from the database.

The limit function in the cursors can be used for limiting the number of records in the find.

I guess this example should help:

```
var myCursor = db.bios.find( );

db.bios.find().limit( 5 )
```