# Mongoose: Using $in operator with a limit

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection of comments in mongodb and I want to get a selection based on an array. I can do something like the following with an array of the offerId field or _id's that I want to query.

```
var offerIds = [123, 456, 789];
model.find({
    'offerId': { $in: offerIds }
}, function(err, docs){
     console.log(docs);
});
```

This works ok, but when I use a limit it limits to the total number, not applying the limit to each query in the array. What I expect to happen when I use `.limit(5)` is to return 5 comments where the offerId == 123, 5 more where offerId == 456 and another 5 where offerId == 789.

Instead I get 5 *total*, so if offerId == 123 has 4 comments, then offerId == 456 only returns one more to make the total to 5.

I have read in the docs about a `$limit` but I can't figure out where to use it or get it to work. 
Thanks for the help.

Comment: You need three queries. Or specifically `n` queries for the number of `offerId` values that you want to query on. The [**`$limit`** ](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) you likely refer to is an aggregation pipeline stage that does the same thing that `.limit()` does as a query modifier for the aggregation framework. It's possible do do this with aggregation, but almost totally impractical for anything other than a relatively small result set. A example is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25177111/2313887) but really, use multiple queries.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you try this:

```
var offerIds = [123, 456, 789];
model.find({
    'offerId': { $in: offerIds }
}).limit(100).exec(function(err, docs){
   console.log(docs);
})
```

Comment: This is what I had tried initially, but the issue is that it will return 100 total, so if offerId 123 has 8 comments, I only want 5 of them, and if offerId 123 happened to have more than 100 comments then nothing will be returned for the rest of the offerIds.